# Difference of Two Consecutive $n$th Powers

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Squares:**
$$0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,...$$

Given the square of $n$, the square of $n+1$ is
$$(n+1)^2=n^2 +2n+1$$
$$\Rightarrow(n+1)^2 -n^2 =2n+1.$$

The difference of two consecutive squares is always an odd number.

**Cubes:**
$$0,1,8,27,64,125,216,343,...$$

$$(n+1)^3=n^3+3n^2+3n+1$$
$$\Rightarrow (n+1)^3 -n^3 = 3n^2+3n+1 = 3(n^2 + n)+1.$$
We can show that $n^2+n$ is always even and thus show that the difference of two consecutive cubes is always an odd number.

**Fourth powers:**
$$0,1,16,81,256,625,1296,2401,...$$
$$(n+1)^4=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1$$
$$\Rightarrow (n+1)^4 -n^4 = 4n^3+6n^2+4n+1 = 2(2n^3+3n^2+2n)+1.$$
Again the difference is an odd number.

> Would that be true for higher powers as well? How can one show that generally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About two consecutive integers, they have different parity. Their any power are also in different parity. Their difference is always an odd number.

for example

$n=\text{even}, n^k = \text{even}$
$n+1=\text{odd},  (n+1)^k = \text{odd}$

Comment: Two consecutive integers having different parities have as the difference of their $n$th powers an odd number?

Comment: even - odd = odd, since odd + odd = even!